# How can I download artifacts from a Maven repository in a private Gitlab project using Ivy?

Tags: gitlab, ant, maven-2, ivy

As part of an Apache Ant execution I need to download a set of artefacts using an incantation as shown below using [`resolve`](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/resolve.html) and [`retrieve`](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/retrieve.html).

The artefacts are located in a [Maven Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/)
that is part of a [private](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/public_access.html#private-projects-and-groups) project. Due to this, I need to retrieve the artefacts using authenticated access.

```xml
<ivy:resolve>                          
    <dependency org="org.some"      
                name="artefact"  
                rev="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" />
</ivy:resolve>                         
                                       
<ivy:retrieve />
```

How do I need to configure such access?

I have

- read the advice that I need to [authenticate](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#install-a-package) to download.
- looked for and not found a means to use [Custom HTTP headers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#custom-http-header)
- looked for and not found a means to use [Basic Auth](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#basic-http-authentication)
- looked at the [ivy settings](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings.html) and the [credentials](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings/credentials.html) in particular.

Answer (score 0):

The solution uses `basic auth` and is based on this [comment on sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4382#issuecomment-663022138).

The [`credentials`](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings/credentials.html) element has four attributes:

- `host`: the name of the host
- `realm`: the name of the realm    (optional)
- `username`: the username
- `passwd`: the password
- The `realm` can be left out, as it is automatically set by Gitlab.
- The `username` is one of the [Custom HTTP header Token type names](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#custom-http-header), in the example below it is `Private-Token`.
- The `passwd` is the value of the private token.
- The `host` must be the DNS name of the gitlab host, below it is `gitlab.com`

Below is the resulting [`<ivysettings` file](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/settings.html): Two [maven2 compatible resolvers](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/resolver/ibiblio.html) are [chained](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/resolver/chain.html), with the first lacking a `root` attribute and so defaulting to `${ivy.ibiblio.default.artifact.root}` which is [Maven Central](https://github.com/apache/ant-ivy/blob/503aafc594b777ffb035a457ed341e31334c23a4/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/repository.properties#L19). The second points at the private repository on gitlab.

These settings can be enhanced to make use of interpolation of the project ID, so this template can be copied. Likewise, username and password can be extracted.

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/maven
```

using the [Predefined Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_PROJECT_ID` via [Ivy Properties](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/settings/property.html) and [Ant environment import](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) as [shown here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html#notes-env).

```xml
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="local-chain" />
    <credentials host="gitlab.com"
        username="Private-Token" passwd="glpat-29Z9xUf-ns4RytWz-nV6" />
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="maven2" m2compatible="true" />
        <ibiblio name="gitlab" m2compatible="true"
            root="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/53177094/packages/maven" />
        <chain name="local-chain">
            <resolver ref="maven2" />
            <resolver ref="gitlab" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```